# Project planning terminology

Tags: translation

We are wrestling with some German translations that have been made by different native speakers. These terms are used in project planning software.

A *project plan* has *tasks* for which *requests* (for resources/people) are made, and these requests are honoured by making *allocations*.

We have the following translations:

```
Project plan -> Projektplan
No issue here.

Task -> Aufgabe
This does not sound quite right to me.

Request -> Antrag, Anfrage, or Anforderung
Antrag is used most often.

Allocation -> Zuordnung, Zuteilung, Zuweisung and even the occasional Aufteilung
Zuweisung has been used most often, I tend to favor that.
```

**What are the proper German words to use for *request* and *allocation* in a project planning context?**
I don't have access to German project planning software to steal from there ;-)

BTW To complicate things the software also has *requests* for taking leave. Should these be translated the same as *task requests*? They are now translated as *Antrag* or the occasional *Urlaubsantrag*.

Comment: It's a multi-question question with the usual issues which discourage asking them.

Comment: Requests for a leave should translate to Antrag. I would go with a general "Abwesenheitsantrag" (because there is a distinction between Urlaub, Sonderurlaub und Gleitzeitausgleich, so "Urlaubsantrag" is too specific).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of **project plan** *(Projektplan),* the term **project management plan** *(Projektmanagementplan)* is also used:

> **project management plan**
> document specifying what is necessary to meet the objective(s) of the project
>
> **Projektmanagementplan**
> Dokument, das festlegt, was erforderlich ist, um das Ziel bzw. die Ziele des Projekts zu erreichen

However, **activities** *(Vorgänge),* **tasks** *(Aufgaben),* and **work packages** *(Arbeitspakete)* are structured in the **work breakdown structure** *(Projektstrukturplan):*

> The project should be systematically structured into manageable activities to meet customer requirements for product and processes.
> NOTE Frequently, the term “breakdown structure” is used to describe the way in which a project may be divided by level into discrete groups for programming, cost planning and control purposes. Also, terms such as “activities”, “tasks” and “work packages” are used for the elements of this structuring, and the result is usually known as a “work breakdown structure” (WBS). For the purposes of this International Standard, the term “activity” is used as the generic term for an item of work.
>
> Das Projekt sollte systematisch in handhabbare Vorgänge gegliedert werden, um die
> Kundenanforderungen an Produkt und Prozesse zu erfüllen.
> ANMERKUNG Häufig wird die Benennung „Projektstrukturierung“ verwendet, um die Art zu beschreiben, nach der ein Projekt stufenweise in getrennte Gruppen für Zwecke der Programmerstellung, Kostenplanung und Lenkung eingeteilt wird. Ebenso werde Benennungen wie „Vorgänge“, „Aufgaben“ und „Arbeitspakete“ für die Elemente dieser Strukturierung verwendet, und das Ergebnis ist üblicherweise als „Projektstrukturplan“ (PSP) bekannt. Für die Zwecke dieser Internationalen Norm wird die Benennung „Vorgang“ als übergeordneter Ausdruck für eine Arbeitseinheit verwendet.

Whereas **resource plans** *(Ressourcenpläne)* are used for **resource planning** *(Ressourcenplanung):*

> **Resource planning**
> Resources needed for the project should be identified. Resource plans should state what resources will be needed by the project, and when they will be required according to the project schedule. The plans should indicate how, and from where, resources will be obtained and allocated. If applicable, the plans should also include the manner of disposition of excess resources. The plans should be suitable for resource control.
>
> **Ressourcenplanung**
> Für das Projekt benötigte Ressourcen sollten ermittelt werden. Ressourcenpläne sollten ausweisen, welche Ressourcen vom Projekt benötigt und wann sie gemäß dem Projektzeitplan angefordert werden. Die Pläne sollten angeben, wie und von woher man die Ressourcen erhält und zuweist. Soweit anwendbar, sollten die Pläne auch die Verwendung von überschüssigen Ressourcen enthalten. Die Pläne sollten für die Ressourcenkontrolle brauchbar sein.

In this context, the words **require** *(anfordern)* and **allocate** *(zuweisen)* are used in order to describe the topic that is given in the question.

[excerpts taken from ISO 10006 *Quality management systems – Guidelines for quality management in projects*]

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with "Anforderung" for the first "request" because it's basically about a requirement. The request is only the logical follow up. For the second one (the vacation) I'd go with "Antrag" or "Anfrage", depending of how official you want it to sound ("Antrag" is more official).
As for allocation, my favorite is "Zuteilung" because it's in essence about distributing resources. A "Zuweisung" is more about pointing than actual sharing. 
Finally, there's "task". I think "Aufgabe" is a decent pick but if you really take issue with it you might want to opt for "Arbeitsschritt" or "Teilaufgabe".

I should say that I have no experience with project planning, so my answer does not represent the jargon.

EDIT:

I just found [this](http://www.philipphauer.de/info/pm/it-projektmanagement.php#projektplaene).